# Toggle a boolean with two buttons

Tags: javascript

There are 3 booleans: a, b and c.

a and b are like buttons. They are normaly false. Only when triggered are true. Like an impulse.

When I triiger the a, the c should be true and should keep the sate untill the b is triggered. After triggering b, the c should go into false, keeping the state untill the a is triggered again.

I want to write it in JavaScript.
I need it for hmi software to control the real buttons.
Thanks.

Comment: If you need to write it in Java, why is this tagged with JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry Barmar. It should be in javascript. I put the code I wrote alredy

Comment: What do you mean that `a` and `b` are like buttons. Either they're buttons or they're not.

Comment: If they're buttons, add event listeners to them that assigns the appropriate value to `c`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I will try with it now and give you the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary operators (`?:`) and negation (`!`):

```js
let A = false, B = false, C = false, a = document.getElementById('a'), b = document.getElementById('b'), c = document.getElementById('c');

function changeC(clickedBtn) {
  if(clickedBtn === 'a') {
    a.innerHTML = A === false ? true : false;
    A = !A;
  }
  else if(clickedBtn === 'b') {
    b.innerHTML = B === false ? true : false;
    B = !B;
  }
  c.innerHTML = C === false ? true : false;
  C = !C;
}
```

```html
<button id="a" onclick="changeC('a')"> false </button>
<button id="b" onclick="changeC('b')"> false </button>

<button id="c"> false </button>
```